# how to use this code in my theme use short code

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
echo do_shortcode( '[karma_by_kadar__simple_player title="' . get_the_title() . '" src="' . the_field( 'download-link' ) . '"  autoplay="false" loop="true" color="1"]' );
```

I want to add this code to my site as a shortcode and get the amount of its name and download link from acf plugin

It does not currently have a download link

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGuh6.jpg)

Comment: Although it is nice to add a picture, adding the resulting html would contain more information for people here to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `the_field()` wont return the field value. It will basically echo the returned value, which wont work when using inside a php `echo`

You need to use `get_field()` instead, which will return the value rather than try and re-echo it.

Returns value... [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Displays value (essentially echo)... [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)